# How to store thumbnails to local settings?

Tags: c#, uwp

I get thumbnail image/icon using the following code,

```
var thumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem);
```

I want to save/retrieve  this thumbnail image to/from local Settings, not in files. But, UWP does not support saving of this type of data in local Settings. I think, the closest solution is to save it as string. What would be a workaround? How to store/retrieve thumbnails to/from local settings? Please code help me, with a best solution, which is best in conversion speed too!

Comment: Yes, you can convert your image to base64 and store as string. But if you want to store images and not deal with files, I would recommend to take a look at [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache).

Answer (score 0):

App settings should include **configuration options** or **user's preferences** according to Microsoft's guidelines and should be kept as small as possible. Images are user data (and large files), so in settings you should keep their directory and use the settings to load them when needed.

**Settings guidelines:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/guidelines-for-app-settings